# How to switch to laptop screen from external display automatically on power loss?

Tags: windows-7, power, external-display

I recently got a external LCD display for my laptop. It is connected via the VGA port.

I am using the "Projector Only" mode by pressing the Fn+F3 function on my laptop. This makes the laptop's screen go black and all the output is displayed on the external display.

There are frequent power blackouts in my area - the display loses power and gets powered off, and each time this happens the laptop's screen won't power on automatically. What I notice is that if I pull out the VGA plug, the laptop screen comes on after a few seconds (Windows makes the 'hardware disconnected' sound). I do not want to have to pull out the plug each time... and put it back in when the power is back.

Pressing Fn+F3 during this time doesn't seem to work and I can't see what I am doing either with both screens gone... help?